# PHP preg_match for grabbing YouTube ID

Tags: php, regex, youtube

i have implemented a function for grabbing Youtube ID and i use the regular expression:

```
preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=|[^/]+/.+/)|youtu\.‌​be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $sourceCode, $youtube))
```

My problem is that this resular expression doesn't collect the id from a URL like: http://img.youtube.com/vi/Di9mQ35zprs/0.jpg

So, how can i change it to work as it works right now but by giving me the "Di9mQ35zprs" from a URL "http://img.youtube.com/vi/Di9mQ35zprs/0.jpg" too?

- THERE ARE MANY OTHER QUESTIONS REGARDING GRABBING YOUTUBE ID WITH PREG_MATCH, BUT NOONE OF THEM ANSWERS HOW TO GRAB FROM A URL http://img.youtube.com/vi/Di9mQ35zprs/0.jpg TOO.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you add some value of $sourceCode to topic?

Comment: It could be: $SourceCode = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/Di9mQ35zprs/0.jpg';

Comment: you can use preg_match('|\/vi\/([A-Z0-9]{11})\/|si', $sourceCode, $youtube); 

var_dump($youtube[1]);

Comment: vural thank you for answering! Unfortunately your answer doesn't help because some times $SourceCode can have many other texts too. I want to keep my preg_match but with the difference to recognize the URL 'img.youtube.com/vi/Di9mQ35zprs/0.jpg' too and grab the ID.